# Can I Turn Off or Remove Map Layers in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer

The title pretty much says it all.  I have a base map in QGIS that I am using with several Print Composers.  In one of the Print Composers, I don't want one of the layers to show up.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could unmark the layer (which you dont want to be drawn in one composer) in the layers panel, then do your settings in the print composer and then mark "lock layers for map item" in the Item Properties tab of the print composer.  Now you have one print composer without that layer.
Now reselect = checkmark this layer again in the layers-panel and create your other printcomposers, which will contain this layer too

[image]