# How to control layer visibility in the Map Composer Overview map?

Tags: qgis, layers, cartography, print-composer, visibility

I wonder if it is possible to choose which layers would be visible in the Overview Map loaded in the Map Composer.
Note that this is already possible for the **Overview Panel** in the QGIS Desktop: for each of the layer in your Map you can right-click on the name and check the "Show in Overview" (see image below).

[image: Overview Panel in QGIS Desktop]

But if I insert an **Overview Map** in the Map Composer I've no control on the layer's visibility: so all the layers (vectors and rasters) that are visible in the reference Map Frame will be also visible in the Overview Map (see image below).

[image: Overview Map in QGIS Map Composer]

I'm currently working with *QGIS 2.14 Essen*.

Comment: Did you try in the Map composer to set that the overview map is not refreshing? At the top in the item properties, under main properties you can set the layers or styles to be locked. This way you can activate the layers for one map in the main application, then set this map to lock. Then set the Layout for your second map. So you have two different Layouts together.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate. I don't think it is a duplicate! This questions deals with different visibility of layers within qgis "overview maps". The answer of the other question (-> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73891/can-i-turn-off-or-remove-map-layers-in-qgis-print-composer) deals with visibility of layers within different "print composers". The solution provided does not work! As I'm facing the same question/problem it would be helpful to re-open the question. Thx